# Possibility to migrate questions wherever you want

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration

I don't know whether it is a bug or by design... But as you see, I have just migrated this question from http://cs50.stackexchange.com. Should it be allowed?

As you can see, Meta.SE wasn't in the list of possible targets:

> [image: migration dialouge]

Comment: Wait....you did what...oh....

Comment: Yeah, he umm migrated without any mod doing anything... And he has just 150 rep...

Comment: Nicely done. Now don't do it again.

Comment: @Shog :( again u just tell me not to do something instead of ***fixing it***!

Comment: @nicael "Look, you can rob a bank by shooting the teller!" "... well, don't do that."

Comment: What if **I** want to abuse this bug for something? Did you ever think of that? No, you only think about yourself. (It'll be fixed, I just don't want to have to clean up after you when that happens)

Comment: @nicael I'm making sure you don't do it again :P

Comment: @Tim You gonna tell us how he did it when you've fixed it? :)

Comment: @Danny wish I knew how, I just watched and helped with the title and post body! I'm not Tim Post / Tim Stone btw :P

Comment: Much improved over your usual "This element is two pixels off!" type questions.  Huzzah.

Comment: @Won't I hope this signifies nicael's return to form he once had, uncovering undocumented behavior that strains the bounds of  common sense.

Comment: @Wood hey, I am just combining these ones :)

Comment: @Tim Lmao totally missed the lack of a diamond there... doh! :p

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nice find!

This hole will be plugged starting with the next build.

Having said that, you should really stop using live sites as your personal sandbox. It's not that we don't appreciate your efforts (we do!), but it's ... awkward.

Comment: Please create a sandbox site then :)

Comment: If I just voted for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958682/usage-of-destroy-method-in-gallery-plugin) to be migrated to yahoo answers, then I don't think the hole was properly plugged.

Comment: @bjb568 I plugged the "you can create several sock-puppets and push the migration through" hole... Was gonna fix the other, but apparently forgot. Derp derp.