# What happens to unresolved flags raised by a recently deleted user?

Tags: support, flags, deleted-accounts

Let's say a user who we'll call "Jim" has raised X number of flags on various posts around a particular Stack Exchange. Those flags haven't been resolved yet by a moderator, i.e., they haven't been marked as helpful / declined / disputed.

Jim then asks for his account to be deleted, and it's deleted. What happens to the unresolved flags that Jim has raised? Are they automatically removed from the moderators' flag review queue before they've been marked as resolved, or do they remain in the queue until they've been resolved (like normally)?

Comment: @AIE. regarding your edit, I'm not referring to Stack Exchange "the network", I'm referring to any of the particular sites hosted within that network. I've seen people call them "stacks", I've sometimes called them "exchanges", but either way, if we're referring to a singular exchange, are we really supposed to capitalize it like "Stack Exchange", as if it were the only one?

Comment: I think capitalizing Stack Exchange in this context is appropriate because you are referring to a "particular Stack Exchange [site]".  Each of their names gets capitalized when written individually.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When a user is deleted, their flags are assigned to [Community](/users/-1), and [the status of unresolved flags is set to UserDeleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251993/possibility-to-migrate-questions-wherever-you-want) with the exception of "Other" flags which are kept unresolved (and thus will remain in the queue).

This is similar to the behavior of flags on deleted *posts*, where Other flags are also preserved... Just in case whatever issue they raise still applies.

Comment: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/community-flags-cleared